# .NET MAUI CollectionView SwipeView change TextColor

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

So I am using a SwipeView with .NET MAUI's CollectionView, what I was wondering is how you change the TextColor.

```
<SwipeView.RightItems>
<SwipeItems>
  <SwipeItem BackgroundColor="LightGray"
             IconImageSource="Icon.png"
             Text="Unread"/>
  </SwipeItems>
</SwipeView.RightItems>
```

I cannot seem to find a direct way, Do I need to do this natively somehow?
If yes can someone guide me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SwipeItemView` to achieve it:

```xml
<CollectionView ...>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            
            <SwipeView>
                <SwipeView.RightItems>
                    <SwipeItems>
                        <SwipeItemView>
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="red">
                                <Label Text="Delete" 
                                       TextColor="Aqua"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </SwipeItemView>
                        
                        <SwipeItemView>
                            ...
                        </SwipeItemView>
                    </SwipeItems>
                </SwipeView.RightItems>
                
                <HorizontalStackLayout Padding="2">
                    <Label  Text="{Binding ...}"/>
                    <Label Padding="50,0,0,0" Text="{Binding ...}"/>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
                
            </SwipeView>

        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

For more info you can refer to the doc: [Custom swipe items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/swipeview?view=net-maui-7.0#custom-swipe-items).

Comment: I am surprised I somehow missed that thanks man